# ODL - Open day light DLUX alternatives - needed for BGP Topology graphing and modeling

Tags: user-interface, opendaylight, bgp

Are there any Open day light UI alternatives for DLUX, what is really needed is a method to visualize the BGP Topology graphing and modeling

Regards
Sami

Answer (score 1):

If you run PCEP along with BGP, you can use [Pathman](https://github.com/CiscoDevNet/Opendaylight-BGP-Pathman-apps) tool to visualize topology.

If your network is segment routing enabled, use [Pathman-SR](https://developer.cisco.com/codeexchange/github/repo/CiscoDevNet/pathman-sr/)